# Dynamically loading children nodes in Tabulator

Tags: javascript, tabulator

```
var table = new Tabulator("#view360-table", {
    width:"100%",
    dataTree:true,
    layout:"fitDataFill",
rowContext:function(e, row){
    //e - the click event object
    //row - row component
    alert(row.getIndex());
    },
    dataTreeStartExpanded:false,
    ajaxURL:"http://localhost/JSONNew/rum.json?v="+Math.floor(Math.random()*100000),
    ajaxError:function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown){
    alert("Sorry Error Loading The Table!");
    },
     dataTreeRowExpanded:function(row, level){
        var index= row.getIndex();
    $.get("http://localhost/JSONNew/id_"+index+".json", function(data, status){        
     var obj = JSON.parse(data);
     alert(data);
      row.update({_children:obj});
    },"text");
    },
    columns:[
    {title:"Name", field:"name", width:200, responsive:0}, 
    {title:"Status", field:"status", align:"center",formatter:"tickCross",formatterParams:{allowEmpty:true},width:150, responsive:0},
    {title:"Acknowledge", field:"ack", align:"center",formatter:"tickCross",formatterParams:{allowEmpty:true}, width:150, responsive:0},
    {title:"Application",columns:[{title:"Application Performance",field:"apperf",formatterParams:{allowEmpty:true} ,align:"center",formatter:"tickCross",width:100,responsive:0}
    ,{title:"Application Availablity", align:"center",formatter:"tickCross",formatterParams:{allowEmpty:true},field:"appavail",width:100,responsive:0}]},
    {title:"Last Status Change",align:"center", field:"statchange", width:200, sorter:"datetime",sorterParams:{allowEmpty:true,format:"DD-MM-YYYY hh.mm AM/PM", alignEmptyValues:"top",},responsive:2},
    ],
});
```

I would like to load the child nodes from a URL everytime the tree is expanded. However since the dataTreeStartExpanded is set to false and the table is redrawn after every update, I'm not able to view the children and am stuck with the root node.Is there anyway to perform this operation?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to dynamically add rows to nested tree data in tabulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54917598/how-to-dynamically-add-rows-to-nested-tree-data-in-tabulator)

Answer (score 2):

The data tree expansion is not asynchronous so it would not be possible to load the children when the user expands the tree as it will not wait for the ajax request to return before displaying the child rows. also expansion elements are only shown for rows that have children in the first place.

You would need to include the child rows in the table when the data is loaded in

Comment: Currently I'm able to load the children with Ajax, but the problem is that the table redrawn is not in the current child level but is at the root level, so is there a way to preserve the level of the tree even after the table is redrawn?

Comment: by preserve the level of the tree do you mean preserve which of the trees are expanded or collapsed?

Comment: Yes I would like to retain the table in the way you mentioned.

Comment: could you create a JS Fiddle or Code Pen of your code working so i can better understand what currently happens

Comment: Ive attached the working website as Code Pen doesnt support 4.2 version yet! Also Ive set the dataTreeStartExpanded variable as true , so be sure to click the expand button twice to view the response! Thanks in advance, Vaidhyesh

Comment: that link seems to work correctly, im afraid i dont understand the issues, the expanded rows stay expanded

Comment: Click the expand button twice to view the ajax response! Thanks for the patience!

Comment: Yes, that follows on from my point about you not being able to load the children asynchronously, that is why you end up having to click the button twice because it has been rendered before the children were loaded

Comment: Thanks for the support!

Comment: Seems this sounds like feature request. I come from [documentation](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.9/tree) I will try to patch tabulator to support `_children: function(){ }` which will return array or even `_children: 'url/path'`. Will this fit the design of `tabulator`?

Comment: Found similar [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54917598/4632019)